# Why is this error shown when the parent exits before the child thread?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


void hello()
{
        cout<<"Hello World\n";
}

int main()
{
        thread t(hello);
        t.join();
}
```

When I comment `t.join()` ,

I get an error

> terminate called without an active exception Aborted
>   (core dumped)

But why do main has to wait for the child to complete? Doesn't the `hello thread`  have its' own independence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the other thread independence you have to call `t.detach()`

Comment: It's not pritning any output after t.detach

Comment: @InQusitive: That is because your program is exiting once main returns.

Comment: Does it mean, all the threads which I create will be inside a single process?

Comment: @InQuisitive: yes, `std::thread` can only create threads in the same process it is used in.

Comment: there is no equivalent of fork method in c++11 and later ?

Comment: @InQuisitive: No, there is no fork. Generally c++ does not deal with processes, the closest you can get is `system(...)`, but it is not recommended.